# adding info to php registration form

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to add more fields to my database registration form. I want to add "firstname" and "lastname" and have already added the columns in the database as well as the fields on the signup form. However I dont know what to change on the actual form that connects to the database (register.inc.php) Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }


    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
    }

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
                exit();
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have added `if` condition in  `$insert_stmt`?

Comment: @KrishR I believe $mysqli->prepare can return false, though you'd probably want to know when it returned false.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to:

1. Update your html form to add the new fields
2. Update your PHP code to read those values in with

   ```
   $firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   ```
3. Update the MYSQLi prepare to include the firstname and lastname (note the extra tags and ?'s)

   ```
   $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
   ```
4. Update the bind to add the first name and last name

   ```
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $firstname, $lastname);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would put it into an array, so it will save me time if I needed to add more columns.

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';
$error_msg = "";
$arr=['username','email','p','firstname','lastname','salt'];
$arrvalues=new Array(arr.length())
for($i=0;$i<$array.length();$i=$i+1){
    if (isset($_POST[$arr[$i]]&& !empty($_POST[$arr[$i])) {
        $arrvalues[$i] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,$arr[$i], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($arr[$i]=="email"){
            $arrvalues[$i]=filter_var($arrvalues[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
            if (!filter_var($arrvalues[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you            entered is not valid</p>';
            }
        }
        if($arr[$i]=="password"){
            if (strlen($arrvalues[$i]) != 128) {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
            }
        }
    } 
}
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
if($stmt){
$stmt->bind_param('s', $arrvalues[1]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
}
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
}
if (empty($error_msg)) {
$arrvalues[5] = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));
$arrvalues[2] = hash('sha512', $arrvalues[2] . $arrvalues[5]);
// Insert the new user into the database
for($i=0;$i<$array.length();$i=$i+1){
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (".$arrvalues[$i].") VALUES (?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $arrvalues[$i]);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
header('Location: ./register_success.php');
exit();
```

}