# adding info (integer) to php registration form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to add more fields to my database registration form. I want to add "referrer" and have already added the columns in the database as well as the fields on the signup form. However I dont know what to change on the actual form that connects to the database (register.inc.php) Any ideas would be appreciated! 
I have seen how to add strings ([adding info to php registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218732/adding-info-to-php-registration-form)) but every time I try to add a number i get the error that is at the bottom.

**Here is what I started with:**

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
}

$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (strlen($password) != 128) {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
}


$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
    }
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
}

if (empty($error_msg)) {
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            exit();
        }
    }
    header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    exit();
}
}
```

**This is What i tried and isn't working:**

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
// Sanitize and validate the data passed in
$share = $_POST['share'];
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Not a valid email
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
}

$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (strlen($password) != 128) {
    // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
    // If it's not, something really odd has happened
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
}


$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this email address already exists
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
    }
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
}

if (empty($error_msg)) {
    // Create a random salt
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    if(is_numeric($share)){
        $share = $share;
    }else{
        $share = 0;
    }

    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (referrer, username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $share, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            exit();
        }
    }
    header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: *"but every time I try to add a number i get the error that is at the bottom."* - Which is? Maybe if you checked for errors properly, you'd find it in a jiffy. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');

Comment: That isn't much of an error. Use what I've given you above then come back and tell us what actual "errors" you may be getting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp1\htdocs\includes\register.inc.php on line 85

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got it! i JUST HAD TO ADD ANOTHER s in the bind_param()

Comment: AAahhh good, glad to hear it and that error reporting helped, cheers.